# Write $\in$ or $\subset$ for a domain in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I think $\subset$ mean a subset of set, i.e. $D \subset \mathbb R^2$ . and $\in$ mean an element of a set, i.e. if $a$ is an element in $D$, we write $a\in D$.

But in the following $D$ is a domain  in $\mathbb R^2$, writing $D\in \mathbb  R^2$. 
Isn't it wrong? Is it not more correct with $D\subset \mathbb R^2$?

> Denoted $D\in \mathbb R^2$ for a two-dimensional domain bounded by the closed smooth contour $\Gamma$. $u$ is definied on the domain $D$ and satisfies Laplace's equation:
>   $$
> \nabla^2 u(x_1,x_2)=0, \quad \text{in }D$$

Comment: You're absolutely right, it should be $\subset$.

Comment: I would guess this is simply a typo, since the error is so elementary. But if many other errors are also present in whatever publication this is from, then maybe it is not a typo, but instead it is an error. [My diplomatic terms: "typo" --- author would recognize it as incorrect but due to an oversight, the author did not notice the error during proofreading; "error" --- author would not recognize it as incorrect and intentionally used the incorrect notation.]

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Arnaud Mortier’s comment:

$\Bbb{R}^2$ is a set of ordered pairs. Therefore, if you say $D\in\Bbb{R}^2$, then you are implying that $D$ is itself an ordered pair.

By contrast, the subset relation $\subset$ compares, naturally, two sets. If you say $D\subset\Bbb{R}^2$, then you are implying that $D$ is a set. (Assuming $D\neq\varnothing$, it will contain at least one ordered pair.)

The explanation in the block quote is definitely wrong in this regard.

Comment: Hi, thanks! With "in $D$" after the equation "$\nabla^2 u(x_1,x_2)=0$", does it mean $u$ is in $D$? If so, I guess we write $u(x_1,x_2)\in D$ (or $u\in D$), "the function $u$ is an element of the set $D$"?

Comment: @JDoeDoe No . . . $D$ is the **domain** in question, meaning it’s the set of values that the **independent** variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ can take. Because of the ancillary information given in the block quote, you can describe $D$ thusly: $$D=\left\{(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb{R}^2:\nabla^2u(x_1,x_2)=0\right\}$$ meaning $D$ is all this points where the Laplacian is zero. In univariate calculus ($y=f(x)$), the domain refers to a set of $x$-values.